# Issue with installation of FFMPEG and Homebrew due to low HDD size?

Tags: ssd, xcode, homebrew, storage

I hope this is the right place to pose this question. I have a MacBook Pro with just 128 GB of HDD space.

Now I want to install Homebrew & FFMPEG - however, with what I have read it seems that Xcode is a mandatory.

Is there a way to install just the required libraries for FFMPEG or Homebrew to run without having install the enormous 10-12 gig of Xcode.

Thanks.

Comment: Please reread the [installation documentation](http://docs.brew.sh/Installation.html)! Only a handful of _formulae_ require a full Xcode installation and most only need the Command Line Tools installed. On a separate note: There are precompiled binaries for FFmpeg and do not require Homebrew  or Xcode to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system the necessary Command Line Tools take up some 303.6MB (I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.3 on a 2012 AirBook). Also, for what it is worth /Applications/XCode.app is only ~6+GB on this same computer.

I don't know that this is a comprehensive storage requirement assessment, but...
~300MB for `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`
~125MB for `/usr/local/Homebrew/`
~_60MB for `/usr/Cellar/ffmpeg/`
~ **500MB** Total Storage

### **STEP ONE:**

To install Command Line Tools without the full Xcode install:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

See also this [step-by-step guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-command-line-tools-without-xcode/).

To uninstall simply delete the folder `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

### **STEP TWO:**

To install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

When using Homebrew, it's good to run brew commands such as
`brew update` &
`brew doctor`
...prior to installations. [See here for some brewing tips](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/18/keeping-homebrew-date/).

To [uninstall Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/install):

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

> Download the uninstall script and run `./uninstall --help` to view more uninstall options.

### **STEP THREE:**

To install the most basic [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX) with Homebrew:

```
$ brew install ffmpeg
```

After installing ffmpeg confirm that ffplay, ffprobe and ffserver have successfully installed and are available in your command line by using, for example:

```
$ ffplay -version
```

If they are not all available, you may need to use the following brew command:

```
$ brew unlink ffmpeg && brew link ffmpeg
```

Some ffmpeg resources:
FFmpeg documentation: http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html
An FFmpeg support forum - http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/
"[FFmpeg Basics](http://ffmpeg.tv)" by Frantisek Korbel

To uninstall ffmpeg with Homebrew:

```
$ brew uninstall ffmpeg
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely going to give this a try. I couldn't appreciate more.